# Signal R not connectedError: Error during negotiation request

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I've been trying to get a JavaScript signal-r client working against a asp.net web api. And I am getting the following error.

`Error: Error during negotiation request.
    at Object.error (jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:178)
    at onFailed (jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:644)
    at Object.error (jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js:664)
    at j (jQuery-2.1.4.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jQuery-2.1.4.js:2)
    at x (jQuery-2.1.4.js:4)
    at HTMLScriptElement.c (jQuery-2.1.4.js:4)
    at HTMLScriptElement.dispatch (jQuery-2.1.4.js:3)
    at HTMLScriptElement.r.handle (jQuery-2.1.4.js:3)`

The following is the code of web api `startup.cs` file

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(HBSWebAPI.Startup))]

namespace HBSWebAPI
{
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();

    }
}
}
```

The following is the JavaScript  code

```
var connection = $.hubConnection("http://192.168.100.162:80/HBSWebAPICopy",  {    logging: true, useDefaultPath: false });
        var hub = connection.createHubProxy("RateCheckerHub");
        connection.start({ withCredentials: false,jsonp: true })
                    .done(function () {
                    console.log('connected');
                    hub.say("success?");
                })
                .fail(function (a) {
                    debugger
                    console.log('not connected'+a);
                });
   });
```

`

Comment: Can you show the whole client script and also the hub?

Comment: You have not set any special routes so try using `http://192.168.100.162:80/signalr` as your url